# How to disable memory zeroing in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, memory, kernel

I 'm trying to disable the Linux kernel's memory zeroing mechanism to investigate its impact. I 'm aware that this is a security feature to protect private data from other processes, however, I consider my set up to be in a safe environment where no malicious users exist (just for experimental purposes).

I downloaded the kernel version 5.2.3 and tried first to “grep“ all “memsets“ from the Memory Management directory (mm) and I started disabling those that looked suspicious. After I recompiled the kernel, updated the grub, and executed a C program that allocates memory, checks if a non-null character exists (exits if it finds one or continues if not), write random information to it, and after frees it.
This program also spawns processes that are doing the same thing.
However, I still cannot achieve it.

What I have commented till now are “memsets“ from mm/page_alloc.c, include/linux/mm.h, arch/sh/include/asm/page.h.

Comment: How are you allocating memory? If you `malloc` a chunk over 128k glibc will do a CoW mmap of /dev/zero which will always be zero independently of any such protections

Comment: Yes, I use malloc to allocate approximately a GB. I thought every time malloc is invoked the kernel performs memory zeroing before passing that memory chunk to a program, no?